# mysql : keep 2 tables with same values using triggers

Tags: php, mysql

i have 2 sub-domain websites with same database structures, and i want to make the users table synchronized.

so i think its better if i could use triggers to update/delete/add same values for both tables.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_student AFTER INSERT ON user
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.type = 'student' THEN
    INSERT INTO student (`id`) VALUES (NEW.id);
END IF;
END;
```

is there are any suggestion how to do that?

or any alternative method to keep users table synchronized so peoples have to register one time only.

Comment: Or may be Federated tables https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html